# Getting error with ajax and action "show'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I got this action:

```
def out_team
  if params[:user]
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user])  # pegando o usuario que a id é aquela que vc vai passar
    @user.update(team_id: nil) # da update na team_id dele pra null pra que ele fiquesem time
    render nothing: true # faz com que o controller nao renderize uma view...do
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => 'teste' }
    end
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```

that's is called in a view "show" via `ajax`
I'm getting this error:

```
 Couldn't find Invite with id=outteam

Extracted source (around line #74):

private
def set_invite
     @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
end

def invite_params
```

Why?
My ajax request is ok, sending `user=3`

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then please accept the answer otherwise ask your queries in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Error: `Couldn't find Invite with id=outteam`.

Error message shows that your id is equal to 'outteam', instead it must be some integer value.

In your code, `@user = User.find_by(id: params[:user])`, instead of `params[:user]`, may be it should be `params[:user_id]`.